# How mange DataBinding in layout included and multiple models?

Tags: android, layout, binding, include, models

I have a layout that include another layout with 2 data model of which one in common. Have an Activity that make binding and sets the models. But there is something that escapes me because I just can't make it work.
I created an example, I publish it below:
The first layout is parent_layout.xml :

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="firstModel"
            type="com.example.databinding.model.FirstDataModel" />
    </data>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/first_tv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@{firstModel.firstMsg}"
            tools:text="firstMsg"/>

        <include
            app:firstModel="@{firstModel}"
            android:id="@+id/container"
            layout="@layout/child_layout"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

The second layout included in first layout is child_layout.xml :

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="firstModel"
            type="com.example.databinding.model.FirstDataModel" />

        <variable
            name="secondModel"
            type="com.example.databinding.model.SecondDataModel" />
    </data>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/second_tv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@{firstModel.secondMsg}"
            tools:text="secondMsg"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/third_tv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@{secondModel.thirdMsg}"
            tools:text="thirdMsg"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

The Activity that use DataBinding is IncludeLayoutActivity.java:

```
package com.example.databinding;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.example.binding.R;
import com.example.binding.databinding.ChildLayoutBinding;
import com.example.binding.databinding.ParentLayoutBinding;
import com.example.databinding.model.FirstDataModel;
import com.example.databinding.model.SecondDataModel;

public class IncludeLayoutActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.parent_layout);

        ParentLayoutBinding parentBinding = ParentLayoutBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        ChildLayoutBinding childBinding = ChildLayoutBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());

        FirstDataModel firstDataModel = new FirstDataModel("Hello", "Android");
        SecondDataModel secondDataModel = new SecondDataModel("World");

        parentBinding.setFirstModel(firstDataModel);
        childBinding.setSecondModel(secondDataModel);
    }
}
```

And finally the models are FirstDataModel.java:

```
package com.example.databinding.model;

public class FirstDataModel {
    private String firstMsg;
    private String secondMsg;

    public FirstDataModel(String hello, String android) {
        firstMsg = hello;
        secondMsg = android;
    }

    public String getFirstMsg() {
        return firstMsg;
    }

    public String getSecondMsg() {
        return secondMsg;
    }

}
```

and SecondDataModel.java is:

```
package com.example.databinding.model;

public class SecondDataModel {
    private String thirdMsg;

    public SecondDataModel(String world) {
        thirdMsg = world;
    }

    public String getThirdMsg() {
        return thirdMsg;
    }
}
```

Why the TextView in layouts are not valorized after binding?

EDIT: I have modified layout and activity with Blackbelt suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution I want to share here, the problem was in the Activity as I suspected, this is the correct one:

```
package com.example.databinding;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.example.binding.R;
import com.example.binding.databinding.ChildLayoutBinding;
import com.example.binding.databinding.ParentLayoutBinding;
import com.example.databinding.model.FirstDataModel;
import com.example.databinding.model.SecondDataModel;

public class IncludeLayoutActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ParentLayoutBinding parentBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.parent_layout);

        FirstDataModel firstDataModel = new FirstDataModel("Hello", "Android");
        SecondDataModel secondDataModel = new SecondDataModel("World");

        parentBinding.setFirstModel(firstDataModel);
        childBinding.setSecondModel(secondDataModel);
    }
}
```

This is the right way to have the correct binding for a layout with a content layout and multi model. Hope this can help someone other

Comment: The key is to use parentBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.parent_layout). ParentLayoutBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater()) won't work.

Answer (score 0):

for the `include` you have to use `app:modelName`. You will have to add `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` to your `<layout>` tag

E.g.

```
<include
        app:firstModel="@{firstModel}"
        android:id="@+id/container"
        layout="@layout/child_layout"/>
```

Where in

```
app:firstModel
```

`firstModel` is the name of the variable of the view model you want to use in the include and

```
 @{firstModel}
```

is of course the ViewModel you want to pass. You can easily pass multiple viewmodels in the same way.

Comment: Thank you @Blackbelt I made the modification you said but unfortunately still not working, I suspect the problem is in Activity